# Is it possible to avoid standard library linking in c++

Tags: c++, std

As is well-known, when we compile and link c++ programs, the standard library is linked in automatically. Is it possible to avoid this? I've written my own native library and I want to link it only.

Comment: Yes, implementations have ways to avoid linking in the standard library. However they don't all do the same thing so you'll simply have to check your compiler's documentation. Looks like one pretty common option is passing the flag `-nostdlib` to the C++ compiler.

Comment: This will be compiler-specific, so you should tell us which compiler you're using.

Comment: Then it's just what @bames53 said, `-nostdlib` is what you're looking for. To make sure that you're not bringing in any dependency without knowing, you may also want to use `-nostdinc`, which will tell the compiler to not look for stdlib headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `g++`, you can use `g++` option `-nostdlib` to avoid linking to both standard libraries AND start files automatically; and use option `-nodefaultlibs` to only avoid linking to standard libraries automatically, it still will link to start files automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible, at least if you are using Visual Studio C++ or g++.

**Compiler Options**

If you use Visual Studio C++, lookup the [option /X](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/x-ignore-standard-include-paths?view=msvc-160)

If you use g++, lookup the option `-nostdinc++`.

**Linker Options**

If you use Visual Studio C++, lookup the [option /NODEFAULTLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a.aspx).

If you use g++, lookup the option `-nostdlib`.

Comment: For the compiler, it is ```-nostdinc++``` for g++ and ```/X``` in MSVC.

Comment: @ManuelAtWork, thanks for the additional info.